# Is there a way to store a component ref in state? Or a more "react-y" alternative?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I'm writing a "pairs" game, and need to store the refs of two clicked card components in the parent state, so I can "flip" them back over when a third card is clicked.  Is there a way to store refs in state that will be accessible?

So I have a 4x4 grid 16 cards, and I first tried creating a ref for each of the cards (a1, a2, a3, a4, b1 etc) , and passing these refs to the components.  This works fine for running methods on those components, but only when I explicitly type the reference, eg flip(this.a1.current).

I can't, however, store that reference anywhere else, so I can't have a state in the parent of

```
class Game extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state= {
     lefthand: this.a1.current;
```

Is there a way to store a ref in state, for later use?

```
class Game extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.a1= React.createRef();
    this.a2= React.createRef();
    this.a3= React.createRef();
    this.a4= React.createRef();
    //etc
    this.state= {
      leftHand: '',
      rightHand: '',
    };
  }

  setLeftHand = (card) => {
    this.setState ({
      leftHand: card
    })
  }

  setRightHand = (card) => {
    this.setState ({
      rightHand: card
    })
 }


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Game">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <Card setlh={this.setLeftHand}
                    ref={this.a1}
                    setrh ={this.setRightHand}
                    lh={this.state.leftHand}
                    rh={this.state.rightHand}
                    cardID={this.state.deck[0]}/>
              <Card setlh={this.setLeftHand}
                    ref={this.a2}
                    setrh ={this.setRightHand}
                    lh={this.state.leftHand}
                    rh={this.state.rightHand}
                    cardID={this.state.deck[1]}/>
              <Card setlh={this.setLeftHand}
                    ref={this.a3}
                    setrh ={this.setRightHand}
                    lh={this.state.leftHand}
                    rh={this.state.rightHand}
                    cardID={this.state.deck[2]}/>
              <Card setlh={this.setLeftHand}
                    ref={this.a4}
                    setrh ={this.setRightHand}
                    lh={this.state.leftHand}
                    rh={this.state.rightHand}
                    cardID={this.state.deck[3]}/>
            </tr>
```

(imagine 3 more rows like that...)

```
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class Card extends Component {

  handleclick() {
    //if this is the first card drawn, addCardToLeftHand
  }

  addCardToLeftHand() {
    this.props.setlh(this.ref);
  }


  render() {
    if(this.state.backShowing) {
      return (<td onClick={this.handleclick}>xxxxxxxxxxx</td>)
    } else {
      return (<td onClick={this.handleclick}>{this.props.cardID}</td>)
    }
  }
}
```

I want to be able to, for example, run a method on the reference stored in this.state.lefthand, and then again for this.state.righthand.

Basically, apologies for the pseudocode but I really wanted to simplify this heavily to demonstrate.

I just want addCardToLeftHand from the Card Component to work.  Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: This is a very 'jquery' way of thinking, Try to think in variables that will store a symbolic state 'isFlipped' and then using this state with a 'controlled component' child to handle how this state is viewed and changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the whole game state in the `Game` component, including the state of the individual cards. You shouldn't store any state using references to components, use identifiers instead. You can add an `onClick` callback to the `Card` component, so the click event can be forwarded to the `Game`. Then, in the `Game.handleCardClick` you can compute the new game state based on the previous game state and the click event. Also, your current approach to managing cards is manual and error-prone; consider using a two-dimensional array for storing your cards and generating `Card` components dynamically.

Comment: yes, I knew the way I was managing the individual cards was a bit pony, it was the only way I could stick every ref in there.  I will give this a try, and then mark solved!  Thank you!

Comment: You're right, I've started again, storing the gamestate in game, and creating the cards programattically.  This has made things a lot simpler.